# In D&D 3.5, need conversion advice regarding npc lizardfolk divine caster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, adnd-1e, conversion, divine

So I'm currently running a D&D 3.5 campaign that started with the old 1st edition "Sinister Secret of Saltmarsh" and is now about to start the "Danger at Dunwater" portion of the trilogy.  I'm updating and converting the lizardfolk and I'm struggling to represent the tribe's divine casters.

For those not familiar with the adventure, there's a "chief shaman", a "senior shaman" and four regular "shamans".  In the adventure, they cast divine spells because that's how 1st edition handled humanoid shamans - they weren't just clerics but they used clerical spells. No ability to turn undead, no heavy armor proficiencies, just a few more hit dice and a selection of spells.

When I read the lizardfolk entry for D&D 3.5 I see that they specifically address a deity for lizardfolk clerics (with domains). However, the same source also says that most lizardfolk leaders are "barbarians and druids" and lists "druid" as the favored class.

I'm mulling over these options and I'd like to know which would be the most faithful adaptation to the original for 1st edition "shamans" converted to D&D 3.5:

Option 1 - Make them clerics.  Simply assume that they don't use their proficiency with heavy armor or their ability to turn undead. This works but conflicts with the creature's stated favored class and leader class.

Option 2 - Make them druids. This is faithful to the D&D 3.5 text but adds an animal companion (which isn't present in the original - the only "animal companion" would be a serpent in the temple but it's connected to a place and not a specific npc); it's not a faithful conversion of the original source.

Option 3 - Make them adepts. This seems to be the most natural representation of the 1st edition "shamans" and "witch doctors" for humanoids but is significantly weaker in spellcasting and conflicts with the lizardfolk's description in D&D 3.5

Right now I'm leaning towards Option 2, but using the Druidic Avenger variant from Unearthed Arcana. I'm a bit worried that with the other leaders (as barbarians) already getting rage it will come across as a bit repetitive for pretty much everyone to rage in every encounter.

Questions - 
1. Is there a class option for druids that removes the animal companion without adding rage? 
2. Is there a cleric option that removes turning undead and adds some access to druid spells?

I welcome any RAW advice but don't want to include any home-brew.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there! This question may be a bit too broad. Could you narrow it down to a specific problem relating to your goal? It's okay to ask more than one question. The Q&A format works best when it can be focused on solving specific issues. This is more of an open discussion.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! The site can answer your two actual questions and even the unasked but implied question *What class best converts to* 3.5 *the* AD&D *shaman?* but it can't answer all three *at once!* Like Jason_c_o said, please narrow this to one query and pose the other two questions separately; I'm certain someone'll take a crack at them all. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Make them Favored Souls.

While this isn't exactly what you were asking, this is what the Complete Divine recommends. A cleric with no Turn Undead or priest training, more savage and spontaneous.

Complete Divine, pg. 7:

> Divine spellcasters from savage lands or from among brutal humanoid tribes (such as orcs or half-orcs) are more often favored souls than clerics.

### Or Spirit Shamans.

And here are your druids with no animal companion. A more spellcasting oriented savage caster than druids with rage.

Complete Divine pg. 11:

> Master of the spirit world, the spirit shaman follows a different divine tradition than the cleric or the druid. Her world is filled with powerful, living spirits, some helpful and some malign. By bargaining with these spirits, the spirit shaman gains power over the natural world and mighty divine magic with which to aid her comrades or smite her enemies.

Comment: The spirit shaman is perfect for my specific conversion and your reference to the favored souls is useful as an option for future conversions! Marking this as solved.